# How to make custom namespace from path, like in Yii 2 namespaces?

Tags: php, yii, namespaces

I found, that in Yii 2 there is an interesting namespace app. For example,

```
use app\assets\AppAsset;
```

There http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-autoloading.html I found info

> When using the Basic Project Template, you may put your classes under
>   the top-level namespace app so that they can be autoloaded by Yii
>   without the need of defining a new alias. This is because **@app is a
>   predefined alias, and a class name like app\components\MyClass can be
>   resolved into the class file AppBasePath/components/MyClass.php**,
>   according to the algorithm just described.

Also I found http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-aliases.html#predefined-aliases

> @app, the base path of the currently running application.

And, when I call

```
print_r(Yii::getAlias("@app"));die;
```

it's printing

```
/home/u1326jyq/domains/lifesim.biz/public_html/dev
```

Am I right or not, that namespace `app` is equal to `/home/u1326jyq/domains/lifesim.biz/public_html/dev` ?

But, if I trying to execute script like

```
use home\u1326jyq\domains\lifesim.biz\public_html\dev\assets\syntaxhighlighter\SyntaxhighlighterAsset;

SyntaxhighlighterAsset::register($this);
```

it's fails with 500 error.

Where is definition of the `app` namespace in Yii2 and how to define custom `myCustomApp` namespace, that will be equal to my path `/home/u1326jyq/domains/lifesim.biz/public_html/dev`, to using it with code like

```
use myCustomApp\assets\syntaxhighlighter\SyntaxhighlighterAsset;
```

that must be equal to code

```
define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(__FILE__))); 
require_once(__ROOT__.'/assets/syntaxhighlighter/SyntaxhighlighterAsset');
```

?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Namespace and alias is not the same. Alias is equal full path on server like `/home/usr/var...` and namespace is a shortcut for autoloader to find a class path.

Comment: Hope this link helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31504980/php-adding-custom-namespace-using-autoloader-from-composer or join our russian yii community for more details as it very huge topic.